# NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngbTooltip' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

`ERROR: 'NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngbTooltip' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.'`

When I run tests locally for my Angular 12 project, I get this error, in all .spec files where `ngbTooltip` is used I use `CUSTOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA`, it is impossible to track the line on which the error occurs.
It is noteworthy that the error is absent with `ng serve`, but appears with `ng test`.
Tell me how to solve this problem, I tried using `CUSTOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA` in the application module, it did not help.

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8W7L.png)
[Console output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC9Hd.png)

Comment: Just add the CUSTOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA in the related module.ts file

Comment: It doesn't work, I already said it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `NgbModule` to `imports` array in `TestBed.configureTestingModule({`.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [NgbModule],
...
```

If you don't want to import `NgbModule` or it causes issues in your unit tests, you can mock the directive and provide the mock.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngbTooltip]'
})
class MockNgbTooltip {}
...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  // add the mock to the declarations array
  declarations: [MockNgbTooltip],
```